# Why does my .NET 6 WPF project not start on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7

I know Windows 7 is old but a lot of people are unfortunately still on it. With that in mind, I made a [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/overview) application using [.NET 6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0). It seems obvious that WPF is definitely supported by Windows 7 since WPF was released in 2006 and Windows 7 in 2009. When I run the application on a machine without a compatible .NET runtime installed, I get a pop-up asking me to install the runtime. So, I did. So far so good. Now, on Windows 7 however, if I start the application, it immediately terminates with exit code 9009 while on a Windows 10 machine it starts up normally. Apparently, [.NET 6 is still supported on Windows 7, the installation also went smoothly](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7556). I'm wondering what could cause this problem and how I could debug it further. Is there a way I can force Windows 7 compatibility in the Visual Studio settings or my .csproj file? I tried
adding `<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` to my .csproj to no avail. Compiling using .NET 5 does not help either. Running the application with Windows 7 compatibility from Windows 11 works fine but it fails on a Windows 7 virtual machine. I also tried using `dotnet publish` to compile instead of just building in Visual Studio, same result.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [.NET Framework system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-client-operating-systems). According to [.NET 6 - Supported OS versions](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/supported-os.md#windows): _Windows 7 SP1 is supported with Extended Security Updates installed_.

Comment: According to [FAQ about Windows 7 ESU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-7-eos-faq/windows-7-extended-security-updates-faq): _After January 14, 2020, if your PC is running Windows 7, and you haven't purchased Extended Security Updates, the computer will no longer receive security updates.

Comment: _I know Windows 7 is old but a lot of people are unfortunately still on it_: People will only upgrade when they find that they can't run the programs that they'd like to run.

Comment: [.NET support for Windows 7 and 8.1 will end in January 2023](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7556)

Comment: Do you have error messages in the Event Viewer?

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek: Thanks, the event viewer was quite helpful, it said: `Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\6.0.19\hostfxr.dll]`. After some research I was able to fix the problem by installing KB4457144 and the app is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the Event Viewer showed a useful entry respectively:

```
Message: Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\6.0.19\hostfxr.dll], HRESULT: 0x80070057
The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\6.0.19\hostfxr.dll failed
  - Installing .NET prerequisites might help resolve this problem.
     https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=798306
```

After some research, I discovered that installing [KB4457144](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4457144) fixes the problem and indeed, it did.